# methods to solve $(13+x)^{1/4}+(4-x)^{1/4}=3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to solve this equation :  $(13+x)^{1/4}+(4-x)^{1/4}=3$. 
I already know that the solutions are $-12$ and $3$ cause I searched on Wolfram Alpha but I have no idea how I could isolate x to prove my answer. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Where does this equation come from?  Please provide some context.

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes I'm new on this site. This is from a class I'm taking at University for future math teachers but there are only problems that we have to resolve and no theory related. I suppose that it's related to analytic geometry...

Comment: Maybe this doesn't lead anywhere... $(13+x)^{1/4}/3+(4-x)^{1/4}/3=1$ denotes specified points on a $\frac{1}{4}$-superellipse

Comment: It may be noted that the transformation $x = y - 9/2$ leads to the more symmetric equation $3 = \left(\frac{17}{2} + y\right)^{1/4} + \left(\frac{17}{2} - y\right)^{1/4}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you are only interested in integer solutions, you note that since you are taking an even root you must have both $13+x \geq 0$ and $4-x \geq 0$, or $-13 \leq x \leq 4$. From here it is not too hard to check which possible solutions work. Granted the assumption that you only want integer solutions may be far off the mark.

Comment: Thank you!! But what if the roots aren't even? I have another problem to solve with it.

Comment: Then it is trickier. See Robert's solution.

Comment: There must be an even number of solutions. Indeed, letting $x=-4.5+t$, you obtain $(8.5+t)^{1/4}+(8.5-t)^{1/4}=3$. Since the LHS is an even function of $t$, for every positive solution $t_+$, you have that $t_- = -t_+$ is also a solution. Since $t=0$ is not a solution, there must be an even number of solutions.

Comment: @RosalieLandry-Ouellet In that case, you'd want an algebraic solution as Robert Israel has given.

Answer (score 11):

Let $y = (4-x)^{1/4}$, so $y^4 = 4-x$.  You then want $3-y = (13+x)^{1/4}$, so $(3-y)^4 = 13+x = 17 - (4-x) = 17 - y^4$, 
or $$ y^4 - 6 y^3 + 27 y^2 - 54 y + 32 = 0$$
This has factors $y-1$ and $y-2$ (corresponding to the solutions
$x=3$ and $x=-12$).  The remaining factor is $y^2-3y+16$ which has no real roots.